# How make a class instance attribute that is a Pandas dataframe directly accessible?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop

I have a `Dataset` class that has some properties such as:

```py
class Dataset():
   def __init__(self, name, data, output):
      self.name = name
      self.data = data
      self.output = output
```

This `data` property is a pandas DataFrame that stores the "data" of the dataset. I'd like to know if there is anyway i can make it accessible through the `Dataset` object without having to access it in order to manipulate data.

I mean, here is an example i'd like to do. Instead of:

```py
my_dataset = Dataset('iris', iris_data, 'outputs/')
duplicates = my_dataset.data[my_dataset.data.duplicated()] # bad
```

It'd rather be accessible, like:

```py
my_dataset = Dataset('iris', iris_data, 'outputs/')
duplicates = my_dataset[my_dataset.duplicated()] # better solution
```

This means that `Dataset` encapsulates `data`, but makes it accessible directly without explicitly using `.data` every time.

PS: I tried adding the iterator behavior to my `Dataset` class in order to loop through the DataFrame rows easily, but I'd also like to be able to use pandas functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your custom class inherit from [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) class:

```py
import pandas as pd

class Dataset(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, name, data, output):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.name = name
        self.output = output
```

And then, for instance:

```py
data = {"col1": [1, 1, 3], "col2": [4, 4, 6]}

my_dataset = Dataset("iris", data, "outputs/")
```

```py
print(my_dataset.name)  # iris
print(my_dataset.output)  # outputs/

duplicates = my_dataset[my_dataset.duplicated()]
print(duplicates)
# Output
   col1  col2
1     1     4
```